# subset matrix based on row variance

Tags: r, function, matrix, subset, apply

I have a gene expression matrix with 32000 rows and 182 columns. I would like to apply a filtering function in R on the entire matrix to subset rows that are among top 5% of all rows with regard to their variance, their maximum minus median and their 90% quantile minus median.

sample matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(sample(1000),ncol=10,nrow=50,byrow=TRUE)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sam I am able to calculate Variance and median using apply `mean<- apply(mat,1,mean, na.rm=TRUE)` and `var <- apply(mat,1,var, na.rm=TRUE)` but i can not put all together in a function to get only the rows meeting all the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step-by-step, you would do something like below. Note I use the `matrixStats` package for more efficient computation of row-metrics instead of `apply`, but that would be fine too.

Of course the quantile with prob. 0.5 would be same as the median.

```
# sample matrix with 500 elements
mat <- matrix(sample(500), ncol = 10, nrow = 50)

# relevant metrics per row
row_med <- matrixStats::rowMedians(mat)
row_vars <- matrixStats::rowVars(mat)
row_maxs <- matrixStats::rowMaxs(mat)
row_qntl90 <- matrixStats::rowQuantiles(mat, probs = 0.9)

# top 5% utility function
top5 <- function(x) {
  x >= quantile(x, 0.95)
}

# combine all conditions
row_idx <- top5(row_vars) & top5(row_maxs - row_med) & top5(row_qntl90 - row_med)
# subscript
mat[row_idx, , drop = FALSE]
```

By the way, reading your comment above, `median` is not the same as `mean`.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to calculate variance row-wise, get ranking and filter based on your desires. Notice that you can pass a vector of values to `probs` argument of `quantile` function.

```
mat <- matrix(sample(1000),ncol=10,nrow=50,byrow=TRUE)

rv <- apply(mat, MARGIN = 1, FUN = var)

mat[rv >= quantile(rv, probs = 0.95), ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    3  260  438  869  402  933  338  867   62   217
[2,]   29  833   48  708  450   79  111  538  984   232
[3,]  142  194  268  559  913  661  794  908  819    38
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I am guessing the only filtering step that has been implemented here is based on the IQR @Roman. I wanted to have all 3 criteria to be met. correct me if I am wrong, please.